# Compile tensorflow 1.6+ Windows 10 no AVX

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, bazel

I am facing a problem when trying to use tensorflow-gpu 1.6+ precompiled packages on Windows 10. As it states in the release notes, the new builds have the AVX instructions included, which aren't supported by my CPU (Xeon 5670).

I am using Cuda 9.1 and CUDNN 7.1 which works fine with prebuild tensorflow-gpu 1.5 version.

When I am trying to compile, either with CMAKE or bazel my build fails.
With CMAKE I get 2 compilation errors and with bazel 1.
I am using this guide as reference.http://www.python36.com/install-tensorflow-gpu-windows/ for CMAKE and for bazel I used MINGW64 to run ./configure and then bazel build command.

I have also tried at first with Visual Studio 2017, now with 2015 and both of them fail to build.
I have all the prerequisites downloaded and installed.

CMAKE version: 3.11.1

Bazel version: bazel-0.13.0-windows-x86_64.exe

Any hints or info would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the version of Bazel and CMake? Maybe your versions do not yet support Cude 9.1.

Comment: Thanks @usr1234567 for pointing that out, I have updated my original post with the bazel and cmake versions.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel to the rescue